# Firebase App Invite not working in release build APK

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-invites

I am working with Firebase app invite for the first time, its working fine with debug build APK, but its not working in release build APK. Do I need to add something in pro-guard?

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-invites:10.0.1'
```

Comment: Do you have the correct SHA-1 registered on the Firebase Console?

Comment: Please cross-link when you cross-post: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebase-talk/Sfbb92rE_O8

Answer (score 3):

You have to update SHA1 fingerprint from firebase console. Instead of using SHA1 of debug.keystore you should use SHA1 fingerprint of your release keystore.

Command line:

1. keytool -exportcert -alias ***YOUR-KEY-ALIAS*** -keystore ***PATH-TO-YOUR-RELEASE-KEYSTORE***/keystore.jks -list -v
2. Copy and paste new SHA1 fingerprint to firebase console.
3. Download a new **google-services.json** and update it in your project.

Answer (score 3):

For those of you who enabled Google Play App Signing, you'll also have to add the SHA-1 key from the "App Signing Certificate" to your Firebase console and use the updated google-services.json in order for the invite to work on apps launched to the Google Play Store.

Steps to locate the SHA-1 key:
1) Go to your Google Play Console
2) Select the targeting app
3) Go to "App signing" under "Release management"
4) The SHA-1 key can be found under "App Signing Certificate"

It took me many hours to resolve the issue and I hope this can help someone who runs into the same issue.