# Firebase Invite not working in release apk

Tags: android, firebase, google-app-invites, firebase-invites

I'm using    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-invites:11.0.0'

Firebase invite works only with debug apk. I'd added the SHA-1 key from keystore to Firebase console. I'd tried using the google-service.json with AND without the release SHA but still couldn't get it to work on release apk. Does anyone have any clue to this issue?

Comment: Are you using the correct SHA-1? - See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41469442/firebase-app-invite-not-working-in-release-build-apk

Comment: Yes, I got both keys from these commands: keytool -exportcert -alias MyAndroidKey -keystore ~/Desktop/keystore.jks -list -v
 AND
keytool -exportcert -list -v \
-alias androiddebugkey -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore. I added both keys to the Firebase console.